# Gradle Fatjar Build Error

Tags: java, gradle, build, classpath, fatjar

I'm trying to create a fatJar with `eu.appsatori.fatjar` plugin.

For some reason I keep on getting this error:

`Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not expand ZIP '/Users/xxx/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.storm/storm-core/0.10.0/59bc38e472630eecfe41fec4bd3cc346626a3f24/storm-core-0.10.0.jar'.`

`Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not copy zip entry /Users/xxx/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.storm/storm-core/0.10.0/59bc38e472630eecfe41fec4bd3cc346626a3f24/storm-core-0.10.0.jar!META-INF/license/ to '/Users/xxx/path/projectName/build/tmp/expandedArchives/storm-core-0.10.0.jar_awree5slcpd7gxsjwz6rwpmop/META-INF/license'.`

`Caused by: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Cannot create directory '/Users/xxx/path/projectName/build/tmp/expandedArchives/storm-core-0.10.0.jar_awree5slcpd7gxsjwz6rwpmop/META-INF/license' as it already exists, but is not a directory`

I have already excluded a bunch of things in my gradle file:

```
fatJar {
  zip64 true
  exclude 'META-INF/license/LICENSE.*.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/*.SF'
    exclude 'META-INF/*.DSA'
    exclude 'META-INF/*.SHA256'
    exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA'
    exclude 'META-INF/*.EC'
    exclude 'META-INF/**'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
  exclude '*META-INF/license'
  exclude 'storm-core-0.10.0.jar!META-INF/license'
}
fatJarPrepareFiles {
  exclude 'META-INF/license/LICENSE.*.txt'
  exclude 'META-INF/*.SF'
  exclude 'META-INF/*.DSA'
  exclude 'META-INF/*.SHA256'
  exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA'
  exclude 'META-INF/*.EC'
  exclude 'META-INF/**'
  exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
  exclude '*META-INF/license'
  exclude 'storm-core-0.10.0.jar!META-INF/license'
}
```

But it's still not working, does anyone know what can resolve this error?

Comment: Which version of Gradle? Which version of the fatjar plugin? Which OS? This kind of info is important for any question.